# Reading date with numbers such as "27.10.82"

Tags: dates, reading

Can you please say how to read if the date is written like this: 27.10.82

Should it be pronounced - 27th October, 1982 or can we say just the numbers? If only numbers are enough, should we say *point* or *dot*?

Comment: It really depends on context. Suppose you're reading out a series of dates for someone else to copy down (in numeric format), for example. They'd probably rather you just said the *numbers*, to save them the mental effort of working that out from *the third of April nineteen eighty-four*.

Comment: Normally I'd read it as "twenty-seven ten eighty-two".  Though note that the ordering is British/European, and in the US it would be "10/27/82".  (And in some scientific and military environments it would be "19821027", with or without separators.)

Answer (score 1):

As FumbleFingers says in a comment, in ordinary speech, I'd say it in full. In some contexts where it was already established that this was a date - for example, when reading out a list of dates, or when going through a number of files in a drawer, reading out the date on each one - i might say "twenty-seven ten eighty-two". I wouldn't say "dot" or "point" or anything else between them (and in writing, I would more likely use / or - than .)

Comment: The *wouldn't say "dot" or "point"* bit applies in many closely-related contexts, in that we never mention the separator when reading out monetary values *(It cost £11.50),* times *(They close at 11:50pm),* etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - But note that you would not say "They close at one one five oh", or "They close at one fifteen zero".  The hours and minutes are always stated as separate two-digit numbers, with the exception that 11:05 would be "eleven oh five".

Comment: @HotLicks: that applies to money and dates as well. I think that whenever the two-or-more-digit number is a number that you can count, we read it that way. Only if the digits are just digits - in a serial number, say - will we read them as separate digits.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Perzactly! It's *nine-eleven*, not *nine hundred [and] eleven*.